# Static Gradient Image vs CAGradientLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cagradientlayer

I need to show some gradient background in the app, so far there are two options in my mind, one is to use static gradient images, the other one is to use `CAGradientLayer`, and I'm struggling to choose between them.

I only need to have three colour stops in the gradient, top, middle and bottom, so both ways are straight forward, my main concern is the speed of rendering, which goes down to `[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient-image.png"]` vs `CGGradientLayer`. The static image can stay in memory, so it's only loaded once, however for different screens either a single image is to be scaled, or I have to have different sized images which increases the app's overall size.

I don't know if there's any article or conclusion regarding the pros and cons of each, and usually which one should be preferred?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an image has to be scaled down, there's massive memory waste. If an image is exactly the right size for the screen size and screen resolution, there is no memory difference in the *running* app between the image and the gradient layer, because the gradient layer has a backing store the same size that the rightly sized image would be. But given the tremendous number of possible resolutions and screen sizes, that's a very tall order, and of course it greatly increases the size of the app *itself*.

For these reasons, I think a gradient layer is much to be preferred. It's better to give the device *instructions* for drawing than to provide the actual *bits* of a drawing — unless, as you say, there were to be a time-to-render issue.

Now, I have never discovered any "speed of rendering" issue with a gradient layer, and I think that to worry about this a case of premature optimization. Besides, loading an image from the app takes time too. The place where an issue is likely to arise is if you're doing this to form the background of the individual cells of a table view, for example, where each cell must be constructed in real time as the user scrolls. But if Instruments revealed that an image was better, then in that case, I would *still* draw the gradient in code into a perfect-size-and-resolution image, but then I'd keep the image in memory and construct the cells from that.

Comment: Consider how a gradients render though. If it's just linear gradients then using the image and applying `scaleToFill` will cause the gradient to look exactly the same as just creating it in code. If the gradient is a shape like radial though then you may end up with an oval gradient instead of a circle gradient, but even then, `aspectFill` will yield the same result as drawing it with code for the new dimensions.